# The meaning of "What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

Title - Feel It

Artist - The Tamperer ft. Maya

> You got it on the side
>   A little one night thing
>   I thought it over and this time I will forgive you
>   Well I'm not letting go
>   But don't forget I know
>   You made your bed and she was in it, no no no
>
> What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her?
>   What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her?
>   What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her?
>   What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her?
>
> Well I'm not blaming you
>   But she's still hanging around
>   And she's so crazy, tell ya now I just don't trust her
>   She thinks she's right on time
>   But I think she crossed the line
>   And I'm ready for the ride, I'm ready, yep, just biding time
>
> What she's gonna look like with a chimney on her?
>   What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her?
>   What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her?

What is the meaning of *What's she gonna look like with a chimney on her*?

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/48/messages/825.html

Comment: Didn't answer the question.

Comment: Come on guys.. why did you downgrade the question?

Comment: It wasn't me, but maybe the downvote was because no research was shown and the answer can be found quite easily from a Google search.

Comment: I think @Hugo [might be right](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+chimney+on+her+mean&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t). That, plus song lyrics are often considered [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75179/lyrics-of-maroon-5s-payphone) (although I can't find where it says that in the FAQ).

Comment: @J.R.: the FAQ doesn't have everything. see meta, or the general culture here.

Comment: I don't particularly object to the question being *asked*, but I see little point in it being *answered* (except by a comment). And I see no point at all in *keeping* it open in hopes of more useful background information that will tell us anything useful about English as such. So that's my extended explanatory comment for closevoting, but the short version is *"I think interpreting lyrics is usually 'de facto' Off Topic"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Straight Dope Message Board](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=443802):

> That's a line from Urban Discharge's 1996 release "Drop A House (On That Bitch)", so they're basically saying, "This woman's a real witch...wonder what she's gonna look like with a house on her?"
>
> Like the Wizard of Oz.

Comment: And then there's also the [black eye theory](http://www.tranceaddict.com/forums/showthread/t-541872-p-2.html), which has some support at the [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chimney).

Comment: @J.R. There's [an article](https://wundergroundmusic.com/she-looked-pretty-stupid-with-a-chimney-on-her-reveals-the-tamperer/) that claims the black eye theory is incorrect, though it does read a bit like it might be an April Fools joke, so I'm not sure how accurate it is.